# Xcode Validation Error: non-public selectors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, validation, frameworks, non-public-selectors

When I validate my project in Xcode I get an error:

**The app references non-public selectors in Payload/appname.app/appname:setResult:**

I've searched for `setResult` in my project, but there are no matches.

I've submitted my app for review with this error...but now I am afraid that it will be rejected...

I use two 3d party frameworks:

- FBSDKCoreKit (lates ver.)
- GoogleMobileAds (lates ver.)

and some Apple frameworks:

- gameKit
- storeKit
- iAd
- AVFoundation;

Does anybody know how can I fix that error?

**UPDATE:** Despite the error I've passed a review without any problems.

Comment: Did you find a solution? did your app was rejected? i have the same problem...

Comment: still waiting for a review.. will update ASAP

Comment: I've passed a review without any problems.

Comment: Seems that it comes from FBSDK framework. I have the same warning.
I am now including Bolts.framework as suggested in the next answer.

Comment: Did Bolts.framework fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Including Bolts.framework in your project will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

setResult may be a property setter… look for "@property" with the name "result".

Comment: I checked... also nothing for "result"

Comment: Do you use or sub-class NSOperation? it has a property: "@property (readonly, retain) id result;"

Comment: No.. let's see whether I can pass app store review